# Line break needed for text-align:justify in list <li>

Tags: html, css, text-justify

I dont understand why this code:

```
<ul id="Navigation">
<li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
<li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
<!-- ... -->
<li class="stretch"></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#Navigation
{
list-style-type: none;
text-align: justify;
height: 21px;
background: #ccc
}

#Navigation li
{
display: inline
}
#Navigation .stretch {
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;

/* if you need IE6/7 support */
*display: inline;
zoom: 1
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2kRJv/)

dont work when you remove line breaks in html, like this:

```
<ul id="Navigation">
<li><a href="About.html">About</a></li><li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li><li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li><li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li><li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li><li class="stretch"></li>
</ul>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dc3kz/)

Justify text-align doesnt work then. Does anybody know why?

Thanks

Comment: if you put a space between the li it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second example  doesn't work because there are no spaces between words (as elements in the inline formatting context cause spaces from carriage returns and HTML space) so there is no space to *justify*.

From the [2.1 Spec:](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#alignment-prop)

> In the case of 'justify', this property specifies that the inline-level boxes are to be made flush with both sides of the line box **if possible**, by expanding or contracting the contents of inline boxes, else aligned as for the initial value. (See also 'letter-spacing' and 'word-spacing'.)

Comment: If that can help you to understand, I made a fiddle where you can easily understand that with one word : http://jsfiddle.net/2kRJv/551/